# Execute a Node CLI command within a AWS Lamda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

To execute a Node command in my EC2 instance, I just use the following in the CLI

```
gsjson 1KIg84G9CXErw2bWhkEHWUkOI4CR-biFeLqCtdypaLU8 fruits.json
```

When I try and execute this within a packaged AWS Lambda function it doesn't work. Here is my Node AWS Lambda code:

```
var gsjson = require('google-spreadsheet');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // Create JSON file from Google Sheet using gsjson
    gsjson 1KIg84G9CXErw2bWhkEHWUkOI4CR-biFeLqCtdypaLU8 fruits.json {
        if (err) {
            context.fail("JSON file creation error: " + err);
        } else {
            context.succeed("JSON file created"); 
        }
    });

    //Read the content from the /tmp directory to check the JSON file exists
    fs.readdir("/tmp", function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);

    });
}
```

How can I execute the Node command like I would in EC2 CLI but within a AWS Lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just paste a command line command into the middle of your NodeJS code like that and expect it to work. In this case you are including `gsjson` as a library and you should use it as a library. In [the official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet-to-json) for `gsjson` it shows multiple examples of how to do something via the command line, and the corresponding NodeJS API code that would accomplish the same thing. You need to be using the NodeJS API code version.

For example your code would need to change to something like this:

```
gsjson({
    spreadsheetId: '1KIg84G9CXErw2bWhkEHWUkOI4CR-biFeLqCtdypaLU8'
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.length);
    console.log(result);
    // do something with the spreadsheet result here
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log(err.stack);
    context.fail(err)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I didn't see any of the Node details you document here when I first accessed the npm page via a different route here. So maybe this is a slightly different library, but documentation is better so may use your link instead. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsjson Makes a bit more sense now, thankyou

Comment: It's weird that it has two documentation pages on npm like that. It looks like one may be a fork of the other.

Comment: Got it working in Node API, can't seem to save it as a file though unlike the CLI. ```gsjson({
    spreadsheetId: '1KIg84G9CXErw2bWhkEHWUkOI4CR-biFeLqCtdypaLU8',
    file: 'fruits.json'
})```

Comment: I believe you have to take the `result` object passed to the callback, and then save that to a file. It doesn't take a `file` parameter.

Comment: Success! Figured the last bit out and outputting to JSON file now. Thanks so much for your help. Here is the code for anyone who requires the same https://pastebin.com/zGRKekhY